# Validation doesn't happen

Tags: angular, typescript, validation

```
 saveItemComment(itemComment: ItemComment) {
    if (itemComment && itemComment.itemNo) {
       if (itemComment.comment && itemComment.comment.length > 5) {
           this.messageService.showCommentLimitExceedMessage();
           return;
       }

      // 1. persist the new or modified itemComment
      this.http.put(this.itemCommentServerPath + itemComment.itemNo, itemComment).subscribe(data => {
        if (data) {
          console.log('server answered ' + data);
        }
        this.messageService.showCustomSuccessMessage(this.translateService.instant("ASSESSMENT.DETAIL.DETAIL-ENTRY.ITEM_COMMENT.successfulSave"));
      }, error => {
        this.messageService.showCustomFailedMessage(this.translateService.instant("ASSESSMENT.DETAIL.DETAIL-ENTRY.ITEM_COMMENT.unsuccessfulSave"));
      });
    }
  }
```

I take this itemComment.comment && itemComment.comment.length to check if more than 5 then return with message
this is my

```
export interface ItemComment {
    itemNo: string;
    comment?: string;
}
```

i even did if true but didn't see error message save just worked

I tried putting that if and then

```
  <label class="bmwLabel" for="itemcommentinput">
        {{ 'ASSESSMENT.DETAIL.DETAIL-ENTRY.ITEM_COMMENT.itemCommentLabel' | translate }}
      </label>
      <textarea id="itemcommentinput" rows="50" pInputTextarea class="bmwInput"
                style="width: 100%; height: 74.8vh;"
                [(ngModel)]="itemComment.comment" >
</textarea>
      <div *ngIf="itemComment.comment && itemComment.comment.length > 5" style="color: red;">Maximum length exceeded</div>
```

still doesn't work

Comment: possible to replicate this issue in a stackblitz for debugging?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you forgot to add **CommonModule, FormsModule** in imports.
please check my [stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-sdqu5k?description=An%20angular-cli%20project%20based%20on%20@angular/animations,%20@angular/common,%20@angular/compiler,%20@angular/core,%20@angular/forms,%20@angular/platform-browser,%20@angular/platform-browser-dynamic,%20@angular/router,%20core-js,%20rxjs,%20tslib%20and%20zone.js&file=src%2Fmain.ts&title=Angular%20Starter). might be it helpful to you.